# Why right-handed neutrino?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, neutrinos, interactions

Interacting part of the $SU(2)_L$describing the Higgs and fermionic sector with one family

$$\mathcal{L}= \bar{l}_Li\not Dl_L+\bar{e}_Ri\not\partial l_L+ \bar{\nu}_Ri\not\partial\nu_R - (y_{\nu}\bar{l}_L\tilde{\Phi}\nu_R - y_{e}\bar{l}_L{\Phi}e_R+h.c)$$

Where $l_L=(\nu_L, e_L)^T$ and $D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+ig\hat{W_{\mu}}$ , $\tilde{\Phi}=i\sigma_{2}\Phi^{*}$ , $\Phi = \Big(\frac{v+h}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)e^{i\Pi/v}(0,1)^T$

I don't have trouble obtaining the possible diagrams however I have a little/big confusion from the Yukawa sector.

From the $y_{\nu}$ term in the Lagrangian only 3-point interactions I got were:

$$-y_{\nu}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bar{\nu}_L h \nu_R + iy_{\nu}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\bar{\nu}_L \Pi^{3} \nu_R + iy_{\nu}\frac{1}{2}\bar{e}_L \Pi^{-} \nu_R$$

And from these I can define the Feynman rules however I have the following confusion:

- why is there a right handed neutrino and left handed anti-neutrino as it should have been the opposite?

If someone could clarify this point and show the corresponding diagrams, I would really appreciate it.

**Edit**

I feel like I'm missing something very basic and that's why nobody answers it. Even if that's the case, I would appreciate someone pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Write all Hermitean conjugate pieces. “Should have been”?

Comment: Yes, from the h.c. parts I can see the left handed neutrinos and right handed anti-neutrinos. What I fail to see is why in the above 3-point interactions I seem to have R.H neutrinos and L.H anti-neutrinos since we observed only $\nu_L$ and $\bar{\nu}_R$

Comment: We only observe those because only they couple to the weak charged currents to produce electrons. The others are not directly observable, but participate in the mass and enable oscillations.

Comment: Excuse the naivity of my question but does this mean I would also have diagrams with L.H. anti-neutrinos with Higgs and with unphysical bosons?

Comment: Left-chiral antineutrinos do couple to left-chiral neutrinos through their mass term, which in turn, comes from the Yukawa Higgs coupling, so, yes, they *must* couple to the Higgs field, as you observe by inspection of that coupling. A LH antineutrino turns into a RH one and a neutral Higgs, in the vertex. Just follow the Lagrangian term.